# get it in my kitchen

Tags: phrases

(**At The Hardware Store**)

**Man1**: I'm here to buy a piece of glass to fix a broken window.

**Man2**: It's a sink I just bought. I'm going to **get it in my kitchen**.

---

What does "**get it in my kitchen**" mean?

Thank you

Comment: Most native speakers would say Man2's final utterance isn't particularly idiomatic. We'd normally say *I'm going to **put** it in my kitchen* (or perhaps, ***fit, install,...***). To my mind, using ***get*** here would only work if there was some *physical* problem (awkward size/shape/weight, perhaps) making it difficult to actually ***move*** the sink from somewhere outside, into the kitchen - nothing to do with ***plumbing it in***.

Comment: I'm closevoting as Primarily Opinion-Based. A few native speakers would accept the cited usage (the intended meaning is obvious, imho), but most wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

It means, ***This sink is for my kitchen*** or ***I am going to install this sink in my kitchen***.
By the way, they call it [***a kitchen sink***](https://www.diy.com/ideas-advice/how-to-fit-a-kitchen-sink/CC_npcart_400206.art) and another verb used with it is ***to fit*** *(to fit a kitchen sink)*.

Comment: "Get" means to install/ to fit_Please would you let me know in which dictionary you have found such a meaning

Comment: "get" would ***not*** normally be used to mean "install" in such contexts.

Comment: It is not an established meaning of get, but this is what you infer from your sentence in this particular circumstance: that the speaker will put it in his kitchen. _get_ can acquire a multitude of meanings depending the context. You can get anything anywhere, "get" is a very general verb and can cover so many connotations.